# 2 x11vnc servers with separate displays showing different windows, overlapping

Tags: x11, vnc, xvfb, x11vnc

I am running a python (includes pygame) program on debian-jessie system with x11vnc and xvfb installed. I want to display terminal window and pygame window separately using xvfb and x11vnc. My approach is like this:

(1.) Start xvfb with 2 screens:

Xvfb :20 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 -screen 1 1280x1024x16 &

(2.) Start xterm with command to execute a bash script, which installs dependencies in requirements.txt, and start the python program:

xterm -display :20.0 -e ./start_python.sh

(3.) Start 2 x11vnc servers, attached to screen 0 and 1 of display server :20

For xterm window (windowid 0x20000e) : x11vnc -noxdamage -display :20.0 -v -forever -rfbport 5920 -sid 0x20000e &

For pygame window (windowid 0x400004) : x11vnc -noxdamage -display :20.1 -v -forever -rfbport 5930 -id 0x400004 &

When I start the first x11vnc attached with xterm, I can connect vnc-viewer on localhost:5920 and see the xterm window.

After that, when I start the second x11vnc attached with pygame window, I can connect the vnc-viewer with localhost:5930 and see it properly. But now I also see the same pygame window overlapping xterm window in localhost:5920 . I need localhost:5920 to only show terminal window, not the overlapping pygame window.